# R: Trying to read several .txt files from a directory into a nested list

Tags: r, for-loop, text, lapply

Sorry in advance but I don't think i can make this entirely reproduceable as it involves reading in txt files but you can test it out quite easily with a folder of a few tabbed txt files with some random numbers in.

I have a folder with several txt files inside; I would like to read each of them into a nested list. Currently I can read 1 txt at a time with this code:

```
user_input <- readline(prompt="paste the path for the folder here: ")

files <- list.files(path = user_input, pattern = NULL, all.files = FALSE, full.names = TRUE)

thefiles <- data.frame(files)
thefiles


Sfiles <- split(thefiles, thefiles$files)
Sfiles

input1 <- print(Sfiles[1])
```

But I want to read all of the files in the given directory.
I suppose it would then be a list of dataframes?

Here are some of the things i've tried:

-i guessed this would just paste all of the files in the directory but that's not entirely what i want to do.

```
{paste(thefiles,"/",files[[i]],".txt",sep="")
}
```

-this was meant to use lapply to execute read.delim on all of the files in the folder.
the error it gives is:
Error in file(file, "rt") : invalid 'description' argument

```
files_test <- list.files(path=user_input, pattern="*.txt", full.names=TRUE, recursive=FALSE)
lapply(thefiles, transform, files = read.delim(files, header = TRUE, sep = "\t", dec = "."))
```

-I tried it on its own aswell, also doesn't work

```
read.delim(files_test, header = TRUE, sep = "\t", dec = ".")
```

-I tried a for loop too:

```
test2 <- for (i in 1:length(Sepfiles){read.delim(files_test, header = TRUE, sep = "\t", dec = "."})
```

Is there anything obvious that I'm doing wrong? Any pointers would be appreciated 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work if the `read.delim` part is correct:

```
thefiles <- list.files(path = user_input, pattern = ".txt$", ignore.case = TRUE, full.names = TRUE, recursive = FALSE)
lapply(thefiles, function(f) read.delim(f, header = TRUE, sep = "\t", dec = "."))
```